# disable Xserver logging

Tags: xorg, logs, x-server

Is there a way to disable Xserver logging entirely? My Xserver is set up fine, everything is working, I don't need to troubleshoot it and the logfile is absolutely useless for me. The logfiles are quite large and just take up space and eat write cycles of my SSD disk.

I see two files on my system:

```
/var/log/Xorg.0.log
/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old
```

I am using `slim` as my `x-display-manager`.
My system is Debian Wheezy

Comment: If everything fails you can try symlink log files to /dev/null.